# How to show references coming from HTML-Files (Angular-Templates) in TypeScript files within VSCode?

Tags: angular, typescript, visual-studio-code, reference

As you know you can enable the following settings in VSCode to see the references in the editor:

```
"typescript.implementationsCodeLens.enabled": true,
"javascript.referencesCodeLens.enabled": true
```

As you see in the image below there are no references (See the code below and the grey reference-info-text above method-name 'myOperations')  `0 references`)

[image]

But in reality, it exists! It exists within an angular template:

```
<div class="some-cool-class">
  <my-super-thing
    *ngIf="ifItIsCool"
    (operations)="myOperations($event)"
  >
  </my-super-thing>
```

Can I handle that somehow? How can I see the references (method calls) from templates too?

Comment: I would also be happy with an extension,..

Comment: I know you asked about VSCode. Just saying that it works in Intellij Idea

Comment: @DPro Thank you, Intellij/Webstorm/.. was my previous editor. They do great job but the company has to change its pricing policy before VSCode dominates the world. 6,90$ per month (cancellable monthly) would be acceptable. Otherwise they loose more and more market share, the software is simply too expensive,..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

EDIT 26 Jan 2021 (from Johan Aspeling):

> Seems to have finally been fixed with the new Ivy language service (used in Angular 11)
> [Angular Language Service v11+](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Angular.ng-template)

===

That feature is not supported in Angular's official language service.

[There is an open issue to add it](https://github.com/angular/vscode-ng-language-service/issues/162) which is going completely ignored for over two years, and [a second issue opened a year ago](https://github.com/angular/vscode-ng-language-service/issues/270) which is also being ignored.

Comment: thank you, the first one presents a solution that gets the points :)

Comment: The solutions seems to be "write a PR to angular/vscode-ng-language-service" unfortunately.

Comment: Yes, I know, thank you. Any progress is welcome, maybe someone is already doing it right now, or someone has already written an extension for VSCode but not published yet? Who knows? I would like to know about it.

Comment: I hope so, too. That's rather poor.

Comment: Seems to have finally been fixed with the new Ivy language service (used in Angular 11)